# Segmentation fault when pushing to queue from different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, queue, thread-safety

i have the following problem:
I have implemented a threadsafe queue in a template class and want to use this queue to send data from one thread to another thread like a fifo.
But for the first step, i only want to push data into the queue from one thread.
When i want to push data into the queue, a segfault will be triggered and i have no idea why.

This is my first linux c++ program unfortunately. I also cannot find any entry in a forum why this should be a psoblem to access a thread from an other thread as long as the acces is threadsafe.

This is the threadsafe queue:

```
template <typename T> 
    class ThreadSafeQueue
    {
    public:
        ThreadSafeQueue()
        {
            if (pthread_mutex_init(&cs_mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "mutex init failed in constructor of queue" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        ~ThreadSafeQueue() = default;


        bool Push(T const &elem)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex);
            mQueue.emplace(elem);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs_mutex);
            return true;
        }


        bool Pop(T &elem)
        {
            bool retVal = false;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex);
            std::cout << "Arrd of own class" << this << std::endl;

            if (mQueue.size() > 0)
            {
                elem = mQueue.front();
                mQueue.pop();
                retVal = true;
                std::cout << "Size after pop " << mQueue.size() << std::endl;

            }
            else
            {
                retVal = false;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs_mutex);
            return retVal;
        }


    public:
        pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex;
        std::queue<T> mQueue;


    };
```

In the main() I create an instance of the Queue with the type of a struct and also a instance of a class which is holding the pointer to the threadsafe queue as a member:

```
ThreadSafeQueue<THDC1000_ToMQTT> queueHDC1000;
TempHum sensorHDC100(&queueHDC1000);
```

This is the class, which holds the queue:

```
class TempHum
{
public:
    TempHum(ThreadSafeQueue<THDC1000_ToMQTT> * pTempHumBuffer)
    {
        assert(pTempHumBuffer != nullptr);
        mpTempHumBuffer = pTempHumBuffer;
        mHDC1000_sizeofReadBuffer           = ReadBufferNumberOfPackages * sizeof(THDC1000_fromDriver);
        mHDC1000_ReadDataBuffer             = new uint8_t[mHDC1000_sizeofReadBuffer];
    }
    ~TempHum()
    {
        delete mHDC1000_ReadDataBuffer;
    }

    bool AddElementToBuffer(THDC1000_ToMQTT const &elem)
    {
        return mpTempHumBuffer->Push(elem);
    }


    friend void *ThreadTempHumidity(void * pClass);
private:
    ThreadSafeQueue<THDC1000_ToMQTT> * mpTempHumBuffer;

    size_t mHDC1000_sizeofReadBuffer        = 0;
    uint8_t * mHDC1000_ReadDataBuffer   = nullptr;
    size_t mHDC1000_ReadPackages            = 0;

};
```

In the main() i also create a thread, that is a friend function of the class, which holds the fifo
The friend is only to access the pointer to the fifo directly for testing.

```
    if(pthread_create(&threads[3], NULL, ThreadTempHumidity, &sensorHDC100) != 0)   exit(-3);
```

And this is the code of the thread:

```
void *ThreadTempHumidity(void * pClass)
{

    std::cout << "Humidity Thread started" << std::endl;
    assert(pClass);
    TempHum * sensor = (TempHum *)pClass;

    std::cout << "addr_of_sensor " << pClass << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr_of_sensor casted " << sensor << std::endl;


    // generate chardevice to read out Humidity Sensor
    //CharBinDevice HDC1000("dev/HDC1000");

    THDC1000_fromDriver  * HDC1000_Package = nullptr;

    static THDC1000_ToMQTT HDC1000_MQTTPackage = { 0 };


    while (true)
    {

        sensor->AddElementToBuffer(HDC1000_MQTTPackage);


        std::cout << "Pushed Data into queue" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    }   

}
```

At the line

```
mQueue.emplace(elem);
```

I get the following errir in the module new_allocator.h: "Received a SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault". Pushing to the queue from the main thread is possible.

It would be really nice, if anybody could help me :)

Comment: `new[]` must be matched by `delete[]`.

Comment: And if you have `std::this_thread` then you also have [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for easier handling of your threads, and [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and a [variety of locks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread#Generic_mutex_management).

Comment: Lastly, have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to locate where in your code it happens? Are you sure it's for the queue? You do have a lot of pointers, and using wrongly or uninitialized pointers tend to lead to seg-faults.

Comment: thanks for the tipps.Yey, i am shure, that the program crashes in the queue, i checked the adresses of my pointers and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a thread safe queue and not to implement it yourself, try [boost::lockfree::queue](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) or [TBB Concurrent Queue (of Intel)](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Concurrent_Queue_Classes.html)

These two are really good because they don't use locks. They are actually lock-free queues which are faster.